# How does correlated sub query works with Exists operator?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Suppose when i'm using

```
select * from emp where Exists (select * from dept)
```

i get all records from emp table;

but when i execute with correlated subquery i get only minimum number of records

```
select * from emp e where Exists (select * from dept d where e.eid=d.deptid)
```

I can't understand how it works??
So in which situation i should correlated subquery with EXISTS operator.
Any real time example??

Comment: Are these real queries? Are you missing a `where` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of a correlated subquery as a loop (although that is not necessarily how it actually runs).  Consider this query:

```
select e.*
from emp e
where Exists (select 1
              from dept d
              where e.eid = d.deptid
             );
```

It is saying:  "For each `emp` record in the outer query, check if `eid` has a matching `dept.deptid`."  If there is no match -- because `e.eid` is `NULL` or the value is not in `dept`, then it returns no rows.

Consider the query without the correlation clause:

```
select e.*
from emp e
where Exists (select 1
              from dept d
             );
```

This is saying:  "Return a row in `emp` if *any* row exists in `dept`."  There is no correlation clause, so either all rows are returned or none are returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (
      select 1
      from table2 t2
      where t2.t1_id = t1.id
)
```

What's happening here is that you're getting the results from table1 that have a matching record in table2.  It does not matter how many rows in table2 match a given row from table1; what matters is that there's any match at all.  Unlike an inner join you'll only ever get one result for each row in table1 that has any number of matches in table2